# What is build_hash" : "unknown" in elasticsearch cluster 7.10.2?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a build a elasticsearch cluster with version 7.10.2
After hitting the cluster URL we are getting below information.
We are getting **build_hash" : "unknown"** , could you please explain it??

is that mean cluster not built successfully or any error??

`{
  "name" : "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "cluster_name" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "cluster_uuid" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2021-09-20T07:12:51.966483Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}`

Comment: So typicality this answer means you cluster is up. It does not say much on it health apart form the fact that it is healthy enough to reply to this request.

Comment: Sorry...but I didn't understand

Comment: if you are still getting this then someone has changed the build that we released and not included a hash